# JsonWebToken error in react native android

Tags: android, react-native, jwt

I am getting **JsonWebToken$Payload** error on android studio while trying to run app on simulator. I also tried to run on physical device yet same error. There's no issue on iOS side, build has been developed. Can anyone please help me out? Attached the screenshot as well.

[image]

I have already tried clean project and invalidate & restart. 
Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution. Just disable the instant run and it worked like a charm.

[image]

ref: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/915#issuecomment-383020978